# Button to delete a role

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a menu with a role setting, a menu role, there is a role setting and deleting a role, here is the code for deleting a role and it works for me the first time, and an error occurs the second time.

```
const {
  ButtonBuilder,
  ActionRowBuilder,
  StringSelectMenuBuilder,
  ButtonStyle,
} = require('discord.js');
const database = require('../../database');

async function removeRoleButton(buttonInteraction) {
  const guildId = buttonInteraction.guild.id;
  const userId = buttonInteraction.user.id;

  // Get personal roles from the database
  const personalRoleIds = await database.getPersonalRoleFromDB2(guildId, userId);
  const personalRoles = personalRoleIds && personalRoleIds.length > 0
    ? (await Promise.all(personalRoleIds.map(roleId => buttonInteraction.guild.roles.fetch(roleId).catch(() => null)))).filter(role => role)
    : [];

 if (personalRoles.length === 0) {
  await buttonInteraction.Reply({
    content: 'У вас нет личной роли для удаления.',
    ephemeral: true,
  });
} else {
 
    // Create role selector menu
    const roleSelector = generateRoleSelector(personalRoles);
    const roleSelectActionRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(roleSelector);
    const removeButton = new ButtonBuilder()
      .setCustomId('removeRole')
      .setLabel('Удалить роль')
      .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger);
    const removeActionRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(removeButton);

    await buttonInteraction.reply({
      content: 'Выберите личную роль для удаления:',
      components: [roleSelectActionRow, removeActionRow],
      ephemeral: true,
    });

    function generateRoleSelector(personalRoles) {
      const roleSelector = new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
        .setCustomId('roleSelector')
        .setPlaceholder('Выберите личную роль для удаления')
        .setMaxValues(1);

      const options = personalRoles.map((role) => ({
        label: role.name,
        value: role.id,
        description: `ID роли: ${role.id}`,
      }));

      roleSelector.addOptions(options);

      return roleSelector;
    }

    async function handleRoleSelectorInteraction(selectInteraction) {
      // Check if the user who caused the interaction is the same as the one who clicked the remove button
      if (selectInteraction.user.id !== buttonInteraction.user.id) return;
    
      const selectedRoleId = selectInteraction.values[0];
      const selectedRole = selectInteraction.guild.roles.cache.get(selectedRoleId);
    
      // Remove role
      const removeRoleSelector = new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
        .setCustomId('removeRoleSelector')
        .setPlaceholder('Выберите, что делать с участниками этой роли')
        .addOptions([
          {
            label: 'Удалить роль у всех участников',
            value: 'remove',
            description: 'Это действие удалит выбранную личную роль у всех участников, у которых она есть.',
            emoji: '️',
          },
          {
            label: 'Отменить удаление',
            value: 'cancel',
            description: 'Отменить удаление личной роли.',
            emoji: '❌',
          },
        ]);
      const removeRoleActionRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(removeRoleSelector);
    
      await selectInteraction.update({
        content: `Выбрана личная роль "${selectedRole.name}" для удаления. Выберите, что делать с участниками этой роли.`,
        components: [removeRoleActionRow],
      });
    
      // Remove the listener to avoid duplicate handling
      buttonInteraction.client.removeListener('interactionCreate', handleRoleSelectorInteraction);
    

      async function handleConfirmationInteraction(confirmInteraction) {
        // Check if the user who caused the interaction is the same as the one who clicked the remove button
        if (confirmInteraction.user.id !== buttonInteraction.user.id) return;

        const action = confirmInteraction.values[0];
        if (action === 'remove') {
          // Remove the role from all members
          await Promise.all(
            selectedRole.members.map((member) => member.roles.remove(selectedRole).catch(() => null))
          );

          
          await selectedRole.delete();

          // Remove the role from the database
          await database.removePersonalRoleFromDB2(guildId, userId, selectedRoleId);

          await confirmInteraction.update({
            content: `Личная роль "${selectedRole.name}" успешно удалена.`,
            components: [],
          });
        } else {
          await confirmInteraction.update({
            content: `Удаление личной роли "${selectedRole.name}" отменено.`,
            components: [],
          });
        }
      }

      buttonInteraction.client.once('interactionCreate', async (confirmInteraction) => {
        if (!confirmInteraction.isStringSelectMenu() || confirmInteraction.customId !== 'removeRoleSelector') return;

        await handleConfirmationInteraction(confirmInteraction);
      });
    }

    buttonInteraction.client.once('interactionCreate', async (selectInteraction) => {
      if (!selectInteraction.isStringSelectMenu() || selectInteraction.customId !== 'roleSelector') return;

      await handleRoleSelectorInteraction(selectInteraction);
    });
  }
}

module.exports = { execute: removeRoleButton };
```

There will be an error here

`

DiscordAPIError[40060]: Interaction has already been acknowledged.
at handleErrors (C:\Users\User\Desktop\bot discord\node_modules@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:640:13)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async BurstHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\User\Desktop\bot discord\node_modules@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:736:23)
at async REST.request (C:\Users\User\Desktop\bot discord\node_modules@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1387:22)
at async ButtonInteraction.reply (C:\Users\User\Desktop\bot discord\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:111:5)
at async Object.removeRoleButton [as execute] (C:\Users\User\Desktop\bot discord\buttons\role\roleDelete.js:36:5) {
`

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is you are trying to reply to an interaction that has already been replied to. Most likely, inside your function that directly listens to the discord interactionCreate event, replies to the interaction, so in this module instead of running `buttonInteraction.reply()` you should run `buttonInteraction.editReply()`.